# How can I protect my users from session hijacking?

Tags: security, session

How do I protect my users from session hijacking?

Comment: Which platform/language? Are you referring to ASP.NET ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880/what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-session-hijacking

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen  that is a terrible answer.

Comment: Note that 1. That posting is auto-generated (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate/45331#45331), 2. It's a comment not an answer, and 3. The question is very similar to the previous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three sections in the [Owasp Top 10 for 2010](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) that you should read.

**1:** (**!!**) A3: "Broken Authentication and Session Management."  (**!!**)

**2:** "Cross Site Request Forgery" (XSRF)

**3:** "Cross Site Scripting" (XSS)

Answer (score 1):

From StackOverflow's creators blog
[Preventing CSRF and XSRF Attacks](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks.html)

Found by Googling "Prevent csrf"
http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=prevent+csrf&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: Session riding is one of many attacks that can compromise a session.

Comment: Good point, when I read this question my mind went immediately to cross site request forgery, but you are right, there are man in the middle and other attacks.

Answer (score 1):

One way that I know of is to check for consistency in the IP address of the user. By this I mean checking that the current IP address match the IP address last used during the same session. This would, however, not stop session hijacking from someone using the same IP address.

Comment: ... and it doesn't stop session riding with xsrf or xss.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of a secret salt known only to the client and server that is established at logon (hopefully an SSL logon). Afterwards the server can provide a count with each response and the client can provide a hash of (count + secret salt) with the next request. A potential hijacker has no access to the secret salt and cannot generate the next hash. Even a non-SSL login can probably establish a secret salt if login is accomplished using one-time-use hashed passwords.