# Dealing with session hijacking in PHP

Tags: php, security, session

Reading through the many questions regarding session hijacking here on Stackoverflow, I've gathered that the only 'solution' to validating a users session is by checking the user agent, which is such a weak layer of protection that I don't even bother to implement it.

So, I was wondering what solutions you guys have implemented? Are you even using PHP's native sessions or is there a more secure solution?

Comment: On the contrary, EFF has recently demonstrated that the user agent is in fact very specific. Find more information here: https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2010/01/tracking-by-user-agent and here http://panopticlick.eff.org/

Comment: @Palantir - Thanks, I'm going to check out that article

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Session Security](http://stackoverflow.com/q/328/), [What is the best way to prevent session hijacking?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22880/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the session id in order to hijack a session.  An XSS attack can go 1 of 2 ways.  The most common is to read `document.cookie` and send it to a remote server (this request will also contain the victims USER_AGENT so checking this value is a complete a total waste of time as it **doesn't prevent any attack what so ever**).   A cool security method developed by Microsoft is called [HTTPOnly Cookies](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly),  and most browsers support this security feature.

HTTPOnly Cookies and checking the client's ip address doesn't stop all session hijacks.  In fact if the attacker has an XSS vulnerability he can just forge requests using XHR on the victims browser and there for wouldn't need to know the value of the cookie.

At the end of the day in order to stop session hijacking you need to plug the vulnerabilities in your web application.   Most importantly you need to prevent "Session Riding" which is also known as [CSRF](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)).   You also need to prevent [XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) vulnerabilities, [Acunetix free edition](http://www.acunetix.com/cross-site-scripting/scanner.htm) is a good tool for finding them. .  Last but certinly not least you must read the [OWASP A3: Broken Authentication and Session Management](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A3-Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management).  A common violation of OWASP A3 is that people don't use HTTPS for the **entire session**.  At no point can you spill the value of the cookie over http,  this has the exact same impact as if you spilled the username/password.  If a hacker is sniffing the traffic he will have immediate access to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Simply log the user out if the request has a different IP and/or hostname. As for people with dynamic IP's - well, logging in again is not that much of a problem.

Obviously the "right" way of dealing with it is implementing SSL.

Comment: Logging the user out when changing IPs will make trouble for AOL users, whose web gateway frequently switches IP addresses (If they still do that, they definitely did 2-3 years back).

Comment: In that case, you could check the hostname if its in any way related to AOL and ignore the IP for a while.

Comment: Throwing the user off their session simply because they are behind a proxy farm network doesn't seem like a solid solution

Comment: Well, other than that there's only SSL. Unless you want to add some hidden GET/POST values or additional cookies, but that's a rather vague way for additional security.