# PHP Sessions Hijacking and its methods

Tags: php, security, session

I was trying to build my own secure PHP Sessions Class, when i was actually wondering what's stopping someone from emulating the session?

IE, why wouldn't a code on test.php

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

Not be able to work on index.php where

```
if($_SESSION['logged_in'] == True){
 echo 'logged in';
}
```

I understand that the way about this is to secure the session by generating a secure ID by locking it to the IP Address and User Agent, but how exactly does that work?

Meaning if i were able to guess the session ID would i be able to set the $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true and emulate the login? Should i then change the SESSION variable to check for login to a more secure one?

Sorry for my questions and hope i make some sense...

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` on every page?

Comment: You should take the WebGoat lessons from OWASP, they help you to understand things better, which is a requisite to create secure things.https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project

Comment: More lessons [here - Damn Vulnerable Web App](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, session data is only stored on the server, so an outside client can't simply create their own session data and send it to your server.

It therefore comes down to actually guessing the session identifier of someone else and assume their identity; this is quite difficult, but not impossible. In a situation whereby an attacker can tap the network traffic between the victim and your server, it's downright impossible to stop them.

There are a few things you can adopt to make things safer, though:

1. **Use SSL**; see also [`session.cookie_secure`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure).
2. Generate identifiers from a good random source, i.e. `/dev/urandom` on Linux machines; see also [`session.entropy_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.entropy-file).
3. Regenerate the identifier when a user logs in or out; see also [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)
4. Use HttpOnly cookies (and only cookies) to perpetuate a session identifier; see also [`session.use_only_cookies`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies) and [`session.cookie_httponly`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly).
5. Use strict sessions; see also [`session.use_strict_mode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-strict-mode).
6. Keep a computed hash of the user agent in the session and make sure it doesn't change, e.g.:

   ```
   $_SESSION['_agent'] = sha1($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
   ```
7. Try to reduce the lifetime of a session as short as possible and use an advanced ["remember me" feature](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice) to regenerate sessions as they expire.

It's also important to know when a potential hijack has taken place and take appropriate action when that happens. You will need to keep track of which sessions belong to which user so that you can invalidate all of them when one of them has been breached.

Btw, locking the session to an IP address is tricky; some ISP's will make it seem that a user comes from various addresses or multiple users come from the same address. Either way, it might be better to keep track of the user agent, since that's less likely to change.

Comment: @user2587774 You're welcome; if it helped answer your question, do consider to accept it as your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Guessing the session id is not session hijacking.
It is harder than to guess a password.
But yes, if someone did get a session id, they would gain full access to the account in question.

Locking by the ID address simply means that you store the original IP address the user used when logged in in the session itself and check it at the beginning of every request to see if it hasn't changed.
This way, even if an attacker gets the correct session id, they still won't be able to use it.

There's a good Wikipedia [article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking), as well as related StackOverflow questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419332/proper-session-hijacking-prevention-in-php), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517350/session-hijacking-and-php).

Comment: You know the `$_SERVER` variables can be spoofed. So, you can't rely on `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for authentication, and specially in the age where [dynamic IP](http://www.noip.com/blog/2012/05/24/what-is-a-dynamic-ip-address/) is widely being used. Meaning, a user could be logged out, because the server changes the IP dynamically.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` can be easily changed by the client, but it cannot be easily set to an arbitrary value equal to that of another client.

Comment: @Simon_eQ So how would one spoof `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`?

Comment: So, what is the point relying in it? If the server changes IP every 5 means, then you should know, the user will be logged out every 5 minutes?

Comment: What? Servers rarely change IP addresses at all.

Comment: @Gumbo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092563/how-to-fake-serverremote-addr-variable/5092951#5092951 &&  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474783/which-server-variables-are-safe/6474936#6474936

Comment: @Simon_eQ, your own second link clearly shows that `REMOTE_ADDR` is a server controlled value.

Comment: @Denis Wrong. I for one can tell you, I made small ControlPanel which allowed me to access mysql. I used to access my database from my phone, and it felt good while it lasted 5 minutes, and I had to log out, because Opera changed the IP for proxy reasons. And please read the first link too, not the second only

Comment: @Simon_eQ The attacker would need to guess the TCP sequence number to overcome the TCP handshake and be able to send the actual HTTP request.

Comment: @Gumbo What he means (I think) is that the client IP may change due to their ISP.

Comment: @Jack Well, I wouldn’t call that spoofing.

Comment: @Gumbo The underlying point is that if your IP address changes you would get booted out of your session.

Comment: @Jack Okay, this is absolutely true, but nobody argues against it.

Comment: There's a delicate balance between usability and security; binding an IP address against a session does neither any favours :)

Comment: I don't argue that, @Jack. The original poster assumed that in the question, I just clarified how the technique works, without passing judgement.